# Bold math using bm within breqn results in compilation error

Tags: errors, bold, breqn

Combining `bm` with `breqn` produces following error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\bm@command ->
\mathchar 30049 \bin@break \mathchar 9259 \mathchar 30050 \let...
l.8 \bm{a + b = c}   
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

It happens only if I enclose equal sign in `\bm`, like in this example

```
\begin{dmath*}[compact]
\bm{a + b = c}
\end{dmath*}
```

Everything works smoothly if I skip equal sign, like here

```
\begin{dmath*}[compact]
\bm{a + b} = \bm{c}
\end{dmath*}
```

However compilation of `\bm{=}` results in

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\bm@command ->
\let \let \let \let \let \let \let \let \let \let \let \let \l...
l.8 \bm{=}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

For `displaymath` or `$$` (inline) there is no such problem.

Compiled using `pdflatex` version `3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)`

Would be nice not to have to remember about splitting `bm` every time. Any cure?

Comment: In the case that the whole equation is bold, maybe you should use `\boldmath` outside the math environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the whole equation bold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

{\boldmath
\begin{dmath*}[compact]
a + b = c
\end{dmath*}}

\end{document}
```

For a bold equals sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

% if you still need bm package otherwhere
\let\saveboldsymbol\boldsymbol
\usepackage{bm}
\let\boldsymbol\saveboldsymbol

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath*}[compact]
a + b \boldsymbol{=} c
\end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was about to check it but for some reason forgot to do so. It solves my actual problem, so thank you for your answer. Still there is a conflict between `bm` and `breqn` which may be troublesome.

Comment: @Paul: Does `amsmath`'s old `\boldsymbol` solve your problem?

Comment: `\boldsymbol{a + b = c}` works fine so I guess it does. Are there any restrictions for `\boldsymbol`? I mean why would I still need `bm`?

Comment: The spacing of `\boldsymbol{a+b=c}` is wrong. `bm` package is rather complex to deal with the spacing problems. There're other features described in the manual of `bm` package. In your particular example, however, `\boldmath` is still preferred.

Comment: You're right. I will definetely apply `\boldmath` as it's all I need for now. Maybe once I get some deeper knowledge on LaTeX I try to fix it, because it looks like just an infinite-loop. Do you think it might be that easy?

Comment: @Paul Using `\bm{a+b=c}` is wrong to begin with; `\bm` should be used with a *single* symbol in its argument; it sometimes kind of works with more symbols, but it's definitely not recommendable.